# TensorFlow: Alternative to tf.stack() operation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pack

The TensorFlow supports stack operation as follows:
"Stacks a list of rank-R tensors into one rank-(R+1) tensor".

My question is, can we use other operations( like tf.concat, or tf.expand_dims) or anything else and emulate the behavior of tf.stack? My intention is to skip using tf.stack

Comment: You can use concat followed by reshape. But... why?

Comment: For example lack of stack by tflite GPU delegate

Comment: Yeah, the delegator i use doesn't have stack operation implemented. So i need to use a combination of other operations to achieve the functionality.
How does concat followed by reshape work? Can you please elaborate maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `tf.concat` operation and with `tf.expand_dims`,below is an example of it.

**Using Stack:**

```
t1 = tf.constant([1,2,3])
t2 = tf.constant([4,5,6]) 

tf.stack((t1,t2),axis=0)
```

**Result :**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)>
```

**Using concat:**

```
tf.concat((tf.expand_dims(t1,0),tf.expand_dims(t2,0)),axis=0)
```

**Result:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)>
```